# How to send email verfication in android using firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

i want to send email verfication to the new user. i am using firebase authentication. I have tried in this way, but it's giving me problem. it's not working

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        System.out.println("Respuesta: "+response);


                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Successfully signed in


                    if (response.isNewUser()){
                        System.out.println("Eres nuevo");
                        auth.sendEmailVerification();
```

Here is the error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.sendEmailVerification()' on a null object reference

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: It looks lik no user is signed in, and you're calling `sendEmailVerification()` on a `null` object. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: `auth` is null.  Assign it before you use it.

Comment: I print the result of response variable and it's showing th user info

Comment: Finally i could resolve. I create a instance of FirebaseUser under OnActivityResult.Then after check requestCode i checked if the user is new and then send email verification

Comment: You can also use this: [Authenticate with Firebase Using Email Link in Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth)